# How can I add additional boards to Eclipse with the Arduino add-on with only a URL, not a zip file

Tags: eclipse

I want to add the following boards:

https://redbearlab.github.io/arduino/package_redbearlab_index.json

Which I can add in the Arduino IDE by going to File -> Preferences -> Additional Boards Manager URLs and just pasting it there

Where is the equivalent function in Eclipse, or how do I configure Eclipse to allow me to develop for those boards?

From Eclipse, I have tried Window-> Properties -> Arduino and from there "Private Library Path" and "Private hardware path", and I have tried pointing them to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries", but that didn't seem to change anything (i.e. no new board options, even after running Eclipse as admin) - while the boards show up (examples and all) in the Arduino IDE

Comment: Until someone writes such a capability, there is none.

Comment: Read the JSON data, find the URLs, and download the zip files.  Then use your normal method of adding boards from zip files.

Comment: @Majenko so the zip files are all I need? I also see some .tar.gz stuff for the tools (i.e. gcc/etc.) - would I treat them the same way?

Comment: If you need tools they will also be in the JSON file.  Do the same with them as you do with the boards. I don't know Eclipse, so I don't know how you "install" things in there. You said you know how to do it with zip files, well the zip files (and all other forms of archive) are listed right there for you. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

With arduino eclipse plugin 2.4 you simply install the boards with the arduino ide -like you described- and you can use then in the arduino eclipse plugin.

Version 3.0 (that is the nightly as 3.0 still needs to be released) contains it's own boards and library manager in windows->preferences->arduino.